# Maximum call stack size exceeded with 2 Collection.find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, meteor

I'm using Angular2 and Meteor. I have an exception(Maximum call stack size exceeded) in my Chrome console since I added that code in my client side:

```
var userChannelsId = UserChannels.find({idUser: Meteor.userId()});
this.channels = Channels.find({_id: {$in: userChannelsId}});
```

From what I found, this exception occurs when there is an infinite loop. I'm sure the error comes from this lines (I debugged my code until I was sure).
Is the problem coming from the fact that the first search isn't finished when the second begin ?

All function :

```
getChannelList(): void {
    console.log('ok');
    var userChannelsId = UserChannels.find({idUser: Meteor.userId()});
    this.channels = Channels.find({_id: {$in: userChannelsId}});
    console.log('ko');

    this.channels.subscribe(channel => {
        this.selectChannel(channel[0]);
    });
}
```

EDIT:

As @MichaelSolati I tried to get only the IdChannel of the userChannel, but I still have the same error ... It returns an observable and not an array. Maybe it's the problem? This is what I did:

```
getChannelList(): void {
    console.log('ok');
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    var userChannelsId = UserChannels.find({idUser: userId});
    var values = userChannelsId.map((userChannels:Array<UserChannel>) => {
        let result:Array<String> = [];
        if (userChannels) {
            userChannels.forEach((userChan) => {
                result.push(userChan.idChannel);
            });
        }
        return result;
    });
    this.channels = Channels.find({_id: {$in: values}});
    console.log('ko');
    this.channels.subscribe(channel => { this.selectChannel(channel[0]); });
}
```

Comment: use `setTimeout(function() { // your code here },0})` to avoid call stack size exceeded problem

Comment: What do i have to put in the function ?
All my getChannelList code, or just my Collection.find ?

Comment: you have to put your infinite code in the `setTimeout` callback function

Comment: The problem is that the exception triggers the timeout, and my code isn't executed ...
So I think the setTimeout just avoid the problem, it doesn't fix it :(

Comment: best practice is to not subscribe in the helper. helpers get called over and over, and maybe in ways you don't expect, so any operations in there should be idempotent. i typically take care of all my subscriptions in the onCreated() function.

Comment: Alright, I'll remember it thank you ! But it still not working though :(

Comment: @JohnDri you should make it clearer which renderer you use (Angular? Blaze?). zim's answer is applicable for Blaze.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to precise ! I'm using Angular2 with Meteor.
I'm updating my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys,

I found a solution that works pretty well !
If you have any suggestion to improve my proposition, fill free to comment, I would appreciate it :)

```
getChannelList(): void {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    UserChannels.find({idUser:userId}).subscribe((userChannel:UserChannel[]) =>{
        var channelsId:Array<String> = [];
        userChannel.forEach((userChan)=>{
            channelsId.push(userChan.idChannel);
        });
        this.channels = Channels.find({_id: {$in: channelsId}});
    });
    if(this.channels !== undefined) {
        this.channels.subscribe(channel => {
            this.selectChannel(channel[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Updated because of the use of MeteorRxJS for the queries. While it's likely not perfect, it should probably put you on the right path.

```
private userChannelsSub: Subscription;

getChannelList(): void {
    console.log('ok');
    let userId = Meteor.userId():
    let this.userChannelsSub = UserChannels.find({idUser: userId}).subscribe((userChannels: any[]) => {
        if (Array.isArray(userChannels)) {
            let userChannelsId = userChannels.map((channel: any) => { return channel._id; });
            if (this.channels) { this.channels.unsubscribe(); }
            this.channels = Channels.find({_id: {$in: userChannelsId}}).subscribe((channels: any[]) => {
                this.selectChannel(channels[0]); 
            });
        }
    });
    console.log('ko');
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but unfortunately, the exception is still here :(

Comment: Wait... You're trying to get a list of channels a user belongs to and search all the channels for them, right? But you're passing into you `Channels` find query an array of the full objects of your `UserChannels` query, not an array of IDs. Try this after you make the `UserChannels` query...

`userChannelsId = userChannelsId.map((channel) => { return channel._id; });`

Comment: I edited my post to show you how I tried. I had to modify a bit your proposition since the query return an array of UserChannel. Tell me if I did something wrong. (It's still not working :( )

Comment: It just hit me you're using MeteorRxJS.... ok... this will be a little bit more painful... I'll update my answer.

Comment: PS There is most definitely a better way to do it than my solution, but I'm a little/very removed from the Meteor world and am just spitballing from what I remember (it's been like 8 months).

Comment: Now I have the error : $in needs an array
At least it's an other error :)

Comment: Maybe its messing up if the initial `userChannels` returned is null...

Try wrapping the subscribe in `if (Array.isArray(userChannels)) { /* code here*/ }`

Comment: Is this a public project you have on GitHub?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(